# Updated to Windows 10 and XAMPP for Windows 5.6.12 - MySQL is now very slow

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, windows-10

Following a recent upgrade to `Windows 10` my `XAMPP` didn't seem to want to work (neither `Apache` or `MySQL` would start). So I upgraded that too to `XAMPP for Windows 5.6.12`. There were a few port issues initially (due to new? services in `Windows 10`) but once those were fixed I have both Apache and MySQL running.

However, now the `php` pages that I am working on, which do a great deal of reading and writing back to a `MySQL` database, run unbelievably slowly. A page that used to take a minute or two before any upgrade now takes about 30 minutes. I can see that writing to the database is very slow and the hard disc is always sitting at around 90 to 100%. I have tried many suggested changes: stopping various services, changing the page size etc but it still runs very slowly. I have checked the event log but there is nothing that stands out as an issue.

I am not sure if it the upgrade to `Windows 10` or `XAMPP` that has done it, and I have run out of ideas. I realise this may sound a bit vague and I am happy to post logs etc but I am not sure whether there is a simple reason for this, or something simple for me to check.

Comment: Have the same problem. Even the Apache itself is too slow (for non-SQL pages). Queries that would take 30 seconds will now timeout.

Comment: Let me know if you get anywhere. It is driving me crazy.